# How to style a path element such that it can be used as a standalone LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, sfdc-styleguide

I am trying to create a custom Sales Path for the Opportunity object and I'm trying to create a LWC standalone, part of the overall Path LWC.

The component structure I'm trying to achieve is:

PathParent
-PathStagesContainer
--IndividualStage
-Update Stage Button
-KeyFieldsSection

The idea of the IndividualStage component is that it will a single component added in a loop under the PathStagesContainer component that I can define behaviour from a single Component, rather than list out all the stages individually under the PathParent parent component directly.

The problem I encountered is that when I added the IndividualStage, the styling looks very different under the PathStagesContainer.

The Standard Path component:

[image: Notice the styling of the individual stage]

My component (Stages added in a loop):

[image: The stages all have rounded edges, unlike the standard component]

The individual stages in the custom path have rounded edges and look different from the standard stage.

The Style guide for Path did not mention any additional styling for the individual stage.

Is there any way that I can continue to work with the individual stage added in the loop (basically make it modular) and get the styling of the standard Path?

Comment: Can you check this : https://github.com/maaaaarco/Salesforce-Custom-Path-Assistant-LWC